# Python, using BeautifulSoup parsing values from a table

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am parsing a table in saved .html document, which looks like:

[image]

the html codes are like:

```
<table id="detailBody" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="tab2" style="display: block;"><tbody>
                                        <tr><td><ul><li><span>15:00:19</span><span class="red">11.750</span><span class="red">5392</span><span class="fr red">↑</span></li><li><span>14:56:55</span><span class="red">11.750</span><span class="red">17</span><span class="fr red">↑</span></li><li><span>14:56:52</span><span class="red">11.750</span><span class="red">479</span><span class="fr red">↑</span></li><li><span>14:56:49</span><span class="">11.740</span><span class="green">6</span><span class="fr green">↓</span></li><li><span>14:56:46</span><span class="">11.740</span><span class="green">333</span><span class="fr green">↓</span></li><li><span>14:56:43</span><span class="">11.740</span><span class="green">21</span><span class="fr green">↓</span></li><li><span>14:56:40</span><span class="">11.740</span><span class="green">15</span><span class="fr green">↓</span></li><li><span>14:56:37</span><span class="">11.740</span><span class="green">35</span><span class="fr green">↓</span></li><li><span>14:56:34</span><span class="red">11.750</span><span class="red">11</span><span class="fr red">↑</span></li><li><span>14:56:31</span><span class="">11.740</span><span class="green">3</span><span class="fr green">↓</span></li><li><span>14:56:28</span><span class="">11.740</span><span class="green">24</span><span class="fr green">↓</span></li><li><span>14:56:22</span><span class="red">11.750</span><span class="red">291</span><span class="fr red">↑</span></li><li><span>14:56:19</span><span class="">11.740</span><span class="red">198</span><span class="fr red">↑</span></li><li><span>14:56:16</span><span class="green">11.730</span><span class="green">15</span><span class="fr green">↓</span></li></ul></td></tr>
                                    </tbody></table>
```

What I have so far is:

```
list_a = soup.find_all('table')[0].tbody.find_all("tr")

for a in list_a:
    for b in a:
        for c in b:
            for d in c:
                for e in d:
                    print e.renderContents()
```

even though it doesn't looked very nice, the result is like:

```
15:00:19
11.750
5392
↑
14:56:55
11.750
17
↑
14:56:52
11.750
479
↑
```

However there are too many contents in the table, I only want the first 10 groups of data in the table. And only the 3rd and 4th items to be put in 2 lists.

i.e.

```
[“5392”, “17”, “479”, …]
```

and

```
[“↑”, “↑”, “↑”, …] #the “↑” can be changed to something else identical if it's a problem
```

how can I achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: Add html  the not the image.

Comment: I think he wanted to say that you should add the actual html code and not only the image so we can help you better ;)

Comment: @SIslam and nablahero, thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will extract your two columns using the `span` tag inside the `li` elements:

```
html = """
<table id="detailBody" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="tab2" style="display: block;">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>
    <ul>
    <li><span>15:00:19</span><span class="red">11.750</span><span class="red">5392</span><span class="fr red">?</span></li>
    <li><span>14:56:55</span><span class="red">11.750</span><span class="red">17</span><span class="fr red">?</span></li>
    <li><span>14:56:52</span><span class="red">11.750</span><span class="red">479</span><span class="fr red">?</span></li>
    <li><span>14:56:49</span><span class="">11.740</span><span class="green">6</span><span class="fr green">?</span></li>
    <li><span>14:56:46</span><span class="">11.740</span><span class="green">333</span><span class="fr green">?</span></li>
    <li><span>14:56:43</span><span class="">11.740</span><span class="green">21</span><span class="fr green">?</span></li>
    <li><span>14:56:40</span><span class="">11.740</span><span class="green">15</span><span class="fr green">?</span></li>
    <li><span>14:56:37</span><span class="">11.740</span><span class="green">35</span><span class="fr green">?</span></li>
    <li><span>14:56:34</span><span class="red">11.750</span><span class="red">11</span><span class="fr red">?</span></li>
    <li><span>14:56:31</span><span class="">11.740</span><span class="green">3</span><span class="fr green">?</span></li>
    <li><span>14:56:28</span><span class="">11.740</span><span class="green">24</span><span class="fr green">?</span></li>
    <li><span>14:56:22</span><span class="red">11.750</span><span class="red">291</span><span class="fr red">?</span></li>
    <li><span>14:56:19</span><span class="">11.740</span><span class="red">198</span><span class="fr red">?</span></li>
    <li><span>14:56:16</span><span class="green">11.730</span><span class="green">15</span><span class="fr green">?</span></li>
    </ul>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

col_3 = []
col_4 = []

for li in soup.find_all('table')[0].find_all("li"):
    cols = li.find_all("span")
    col_3.append(cols[2].text)
    col_4.append(cols[3].text)

print col_3 
print col_4
```

This would give you the following output:

```
[u'5392', u'17', u'479', u'6', u'333', u'21', u'15', u'35', u'11', u'3', u'24', u'291', u'198', u'15']
[u'?', u'?', u'?', u'?', u'?', u'?', u'?', u'?', u'?', u'?', u'?', u'?', u'?', u'?']
```

Comment: this's perfect. thanks for the guiding, which benefits many learners.

Answer (score 2):

Why didn't you tried to find all span items directly because that is what you actually want or not?
So instead of

```
list_a = soup.find_all('table')[0].tbody.find_all("tr")
```

try

```
list_a = soup.find_all('table')[0].tbody.find_all("tr")[0].find_all("span")
```

I don't know if you're table only has one row. If yes this shoudl work and give you all the spans and you just skip the one's you do not need. If you got multiple rows you have to iterate over the rows like this

```
list_a = soup.find_all('table')[0].tbody.find_all("tr")
for a in list_a:
    a.find_all("span")
```

and again you will get all span items. I hope this leads you in the right direction!

Comment: thanks for the help. hope you don't mind I choose another which answered all my questions. :)